# Laravel Connect To Wamp Phpmyadmin in windows

Tags: laravel

I am new in laravel framework and I have no idea on how to view my saved data in laravel. I already edited the .env to the correct values

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:YfTvtpSEf86ZR0K+MiruFqbIrmfYzMUVT4XWtj5ovLM=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=application
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=admin

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

am I doing something wrong? whenever i try to manipulate the database in my code it says SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES). for user "homestead"? but I already set the username into admin in my DB_USERNAME i'm so confused. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: do `composer dump-autoload -o` and run your application

Comment: Hi, what does it do? anyway just fixed it right now by restarting my laravel serve. thank you for this additional information

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it :D Just needed to restart my laravel server. maybe its some caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

and also please restart your laravel application

or please check `config/database.php`

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'application'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'admin'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'admin'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
]
```